# Hide output from echo json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I was passing an array in php to Javascript using json_encode and ajax. It seems that the only way is to use

```
echo json_encode($var)
```

which also prints out the information of $var on the page because of echo. Is there an easy way to hide the output? My code was like the follows,

main.php

```
<?php
include_once('testing.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

testing.php

```
<?php
$var=array('1','2','3','4','5');
echo json_encode($var);
?>
```

testing.js

```
$.ajax({
        url : './testing.php',
        type : "GET",
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (result) {
           showstaff(result);
        }
    });

function showstaff(x){
  console.log(x);
}
```

Running main.php print out the array('1','2','3','4','5') on the page and show the array in the console, but what I need is to just show the array in the console (i.e. hide the results from the page).

Comment: `<script>var data = <?php echo  json_encode($var); ?>;</script>`

Comment: @adeneo He says he's using AJAX. That would be if he's generating the Javascript in PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by "also prints the information of $var"? It shouldn't print anything other than the JSON encoding.

Comment: I suspect something else is causing additional output, maybe you have `var_dump($var)` somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure you're doing this in the function that's run when you make an AJAX call? You shouldn't do this in the HTML code.

Comment: @Barmar - indeed, didn't see the part about ajax, as it wouldn't make any sense to hide anything from an ajax call, nor would it output anything ..... so, this question just made no sense at all !

Comment: @Barmar I tried $x=json_encode($var), and console.log($x) gave me a proper string of $var in the console. It means the output of json_encode($var) is a string. When echo a string in php, are we not supposed to get some print on the page?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. `$x = json_encode($var)` is PHP, but `console.log($x)` is Javascript. JS can't access PHP variables like that.

Comment: When you use AJAX, the output of the script isn't printed on the page, it's sent to the Javascript code that's processing the AJAX response. Then the JS code decides what to do with it.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I omitted a bit details. The echo json_encode() part was written in a .php file, in that php file I did echo "<script>console.log(".$x.");</script>"; to see output in console. Thanks for keeping up with this so quickly btw.

Comment: I still don't understand why this is an issue when the PHP script is being called using AJAX. You need to post the actual code in the question, because your brief description is obviously not matching what you're really doing.

Comment: Or maybe you're confused about how to write a PHP script that's used with AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I'm very confused. I add more details to this question. Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `include_once('testing.php')` in `main.php`. When `main.php` is sent to the browser, it will load `testing.js`, which will then execute `testing.php` via the AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks. I actually used including_once function in a html in order to use php for html design. I got both the console result and page print-out.

Comment: It makes no sense to use `echo json_encode()` in `main.php`. JSON is used for responding to AJAX, it doesn't belong on a normal HTML page.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's a bad idea to mix php and html coding in a single file.

Comment: You can do it, but you have to do extra checks. If you use `type: "POST"` in the AJAX call, the PHP can do `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { echo json_encode($var); }`

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance on this problem. I think we finally got there after a long run. Actually when I used if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") { echo json_encode($var); }. it worked! Many thanks.

Comment: That test will also be true when you load `main.php` normally in the browser, not just when you use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var object = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;
</script>
```

Hope it helps, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Actually the echo json_ecnode($var) part was written in a .php file, while I tried to call the php variable $var in a separate .js file using ajax. It's not quite clear to me where your script should fit in.